# How to efficiently pass initial value to get_variable when the data does not fit in memory?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I want to create a variable using tf.get_variable and initalize it using the embeddings from a file, Code 1:

```
with tf.name_scope("embedding"):
                init = tf.constant_initializer(np.loadtxt(embed_file))
                self.ent_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="ent_embedding", shape=[entity_total, sizeE],
                                                      initializer=init)
                self.rel_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="rel_embedding", shape=[relation_total, sizeR],
                                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
```

But the embeddings are too large to fit in the memory, so I tried to read one line at a time update self.ent_embeddings so that it has the same effect as Code 1 above. Code 2:

```
with tf.name_scope("embedding"):
                self.ent_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="ent_embedding", shape=[entity_total, sizeE],
                                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=True))
                #tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() # Reuse variables

                self.rel_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="rel_embedding", shape=[relation_total, sizeR],
                                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))

                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() # Reuse variables


                def cond(size, i):
                    return tf.less(i,size)

                def body(size, i):

                    self.ent_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="ent_embedding", shape=[entity_total, sizeE],
                                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
                    self.ent_embeddings = tf.scatter_update(self.ent_embeddings, [i], oldembs_iterator.get_next())

                    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() # Reuse variables
                    with tf.control_dependencies([self.ent_embeddings]):
                        return (size, i+1)

                with tf.Session() as sess:
                    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
                    sess.run(init)
                    i = tf.constant(0)
                    size = tf.constant(int(oldembs_total))
                    _,i = tf.while_loop(cond,
                                    body,
                                    [size, i])

                    self.ent_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name="ent_embedding", shape=[entity_total, sizeE],
                                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
                    sess.run([self.ent_embeddings,i])
```

But when I access self.ent_embeddings outside of "with tf.name_scope("embedding"):" in code 2, I could not get the desired result (The embeddings are different than what the code 1 returns). But I do not why? Is there any way to solve this problem?